# Bending brass sheets

Tags: metal

I would like to bend a long edge (about 500mm) of a brass sheet (either 0.5mm or 1mm) into a U-shape.

I understand that brass is best bent warm. Is this achievable at home (without large machines)? Is it possible to bend it in sections

1. `_______` before bending
2. `_—_—_—_` bending parts
3. `———————` after bending

The instructions [here](http://www.cabaret.co.uk/working-with-brass-part-2-bending-brass-dugs-tips-14/)

[image]

don't mention heating and don't easily adapt to larger edges (500mm), as the strength required is probably too large.

(I am using the sheet as a drawer and would prefer the bent edge over an edge protector, which would stop things from sliding out easily.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a jig to serve as a bench (bending) brake, if you have some heavy-duty C-clamps. You need to cut some strips of lumber as long as the metal strip, and clamp them tightly to the sheet along both sides of the bend location. Bevel the edges about 50 deg on the side you are bending toward.

Here is a sketch to start you off:

[image: bench brake substitute jig suggestion]

Comment: Should I ignore the heating of the metal before bending?

Comment: I don't have any reference for warming brass before working it. If your reference meant heating it until it is soft, you can't do that here without setting the wood on fire. If your reference meant warming it to 200..250 to avoid cracking, then it's possible. - I don't think 500mm sheet brass will crack with this rig, even at room temp.

Answer (score 3):

Find a local metalshop, ask them to bend it for you. Should be cheap. Or you could spend a hundred bucks or so on a cheap bending brake. Or you can continue to wrestle with it.